# How to convert string with exponent to float?

Tags: .net, string, floating-point, exponent

I have the following string: "3.39112632978e+001" which I need to convert to float. WolframAlpha says that the result of this value is 33.9112632978 which evidently I should get somehow and I couldn't figure out how.

```
Single.Parse("3.39112632978e+001") gives 3.39112624E+12

Double.Parse("3.39112632978e+001") gives 3391126329780.0

float.Parse("3.39112632978e+001") gives 3.39112624E+12
```

What should I do?

Comment: What are your current Windows localization settings (I get 33. from that double parse, but I get what you get when I have a `,` rather than a `.` - this screams `CultureInfo` problem :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing a localization issue wherein the `.` is being interpreted as a thousands separator instead of as a decimal separator. Are you in, say, Europe?

Try this:

```
float f = Single.Parse("3.39112632978e+001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Output:

```
33.91126
```

Note that if we replace the `.` by a `,` then we see the behavior that you are experiencing:

```
float g = Single.Parse("3,39112632978e+001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(g);
```

Output:

```
3.391126E+12
```

This supports my belief that you are experiencing a localization issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think, this thread gives hints to your question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e482cda0-6510-4d2c-b830-11e57e04f65d (and the `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float` is one of the key things here - it changes how the `.` is interpreted)