# Converting float to string and getting exact value

Tags: .net, string, floating-point

This is follow up for my last question about [converting string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238070/how-to-convert-string-with-exponent-to-float)

I have this value stored in a float variable: **33.9112625** (it's thirty three) and I need to convert it to string and get the exact value but I'm unable to do so. float.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) gives me "33.91126" as result. I tried .ToString("G"), "G7" and CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat but they didn't help. How can I convert a float to string and get the exact same value?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact value you have stored?

Comment: If you want exact values, floats are a really bad choice for a data type.

Comment: If you want exact decimal representations, you should be using Decimals.

Comment: The float type can only reliably store 7 significant digits.  You'll never get the last two digits in that number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Skeet provides [an article explaining](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint) this along with C# code to print the exact representation.

Comment: Could you provide a summary of the article in case it expires?

Answer (score 8):

First, you aren't saving "exact" values in a float (System.Single).  For details, see [David Goldberg's article on floating point precision](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edavid/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf).

That being said, if you want to convert this, you'll need to specify extra precision to Single.ToString().  By using "G", you get the [default precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString), which is 7.  In your case, to see the value you've shown, you'd need 9, so you could use "G9".

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to `Decimal` type, I tried it using `float` but it would only show 5 decimal places.

```
decimal d = 33.9112625M;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.ToString(System.Globalization.InvariantCulture));
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: At least it would be favourable to put a comment in as to why it was downvoted? Ignorant...you'd do the exact same thing I'm sure if you cared enough to improve yourself!